# Rails CMS without database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a very simple CMS. I will be the only editor, so I'd like to keep my code and content in the same place if possible.

What's the best way to go about doing this? Basically, I would like to use static code as my model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a Rails CMS, don't know of any that uses static files instead of a database. Rails was designed for databases. I'd say the closest you could get would be to use something like [Refinery](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms) with SQLite instead of MySQL. SQLite is still a database but it stores your "database" as a file in `db/production.sqlite3` without needing a database server.

However, if Rails isn't a requirement, you could try [Nesta](http://effectif.com/nesta) (it uses Ruby and [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) instead of Rails). I haven't used it myself but it sounds like almost exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up using [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll), it was more close to what I was looking for than Nesta.